# system.array does not contain a definition for ToArray and no extension method

Tags: c#

I was trying to copy files from FTP using FTPWebRequest in my wcf block here is the code below.

```
  long cl = response.ContentLength;
                int bufferSize = 4155;
                int readCount=0;
                int i = 0;
                byte[] newbuffer;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //Follow the Using here
                using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    readCount = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (readCount > 0)
                    {
                        newbuffer = new byte[readCount];
                        Array.Copy(buffer, newbuffer, readCount);
                        outputStream.Write(newbuffer.ToArray(), 0, readCount);


                    }
                    outputStream.Close();
                }

               ftpStream.Close();

                response.Close();

            }
```

in the "USING" block was suggested by "DotNetUser" member,i found one thing in the code 
outputStream.Write(newbuffer.ToArray(), 0, readCount); throwing an exception at "ToArray",it suppose to be like outputStream.Write(newbuffer, 0, readCount);please suggest me.

Comment: `Array` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` which is the type the `ToArray` method extends. `newbuffer` is already an `Array` type why would you need to convert it?

Comment: You wrote your own answer at the end of your question.  Did you try this and did it work for you?  If not, what error are you given?

Comment: @M.Babcock: Where did you get the false idea that arrays don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`? From the specification: "In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the `Array` class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces." Of course, your second point is correct.

Comment: @Jason - According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) for `Array`, it only implements `ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable`. None of the interfaces you listed are included. Have I misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: @M.Babcock: The Remarks section of that same documentation page says: *"...the `Array` class implements the `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the `Array` class, and there are no reference topics for interface members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type (explicit interface implementations)."*

Comment: @LukeH - Then they would also not be visible to Visual Studio's intellisense which would explain why the extension methods don't appear in the member list. This would eliminate the benefit of the extension method syntactic sugar so they may as well not implement the interfaces.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Nope, intellisense in VS works fine. For example, all the LINQ methods that extend `IEnumerable<T>` will show up for arrays, so long as you have a `using System.Linq` directive.

Comment: @LukeH - Are you sure about that? I tested it before posting my response and sure enough only the `IEnumerable` extension methods appear. (Using VS Ultimate 2010).

Comment: @LukeH - I tested further and `var a = byte[10]` contains the extension methods however when defining `var a = new Array()` a does not contain the extension methods. It appears the `Array` type (as my original comment mentions) doesn't have the `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods however arrays defined using the `[]` syntax they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newbuffer` variable is already an array, so you don't need to convert it to an array. You can just use:

```
outputStream.Write(newbuffer, 0, readCount);
```

However, there is no reason to create the `newbuffer` array at all. Just write the data from the `buffer` array:

```
readCount = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
if (readCount > 0) {
  outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}
```

However, this will only read the first block of data from the stream. You need to loop until there is no more data to read:

```
do {
  readCount = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  if (readCount > 0) {
    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
  }
} until (readCount == 0);
```

Comment: It should also be noted that if you're using .NET 4, you can utilize the new `CopyTo` stream extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot M.Babcock,Moozhe,Jason,LukeH,Guffa,BrokenGlass for your great help

Comment: why i got the Minus reputation for this question guys ?

Answer (score 3):

Why `ToArray()`? `newbuffer` is an array of bytes and you may write it like:

```
outputStream.Write(newbuffer, 0, readCount);
```

However you may import `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: thanks for your help.Already changed my code to outputStream.Write(newbuffer, 0, readCount); even it works with out import System.Linq namespace.

Comment: @Usher - Typo. No need to import System.Linq if you don't want to use extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temporary buffer - just copy the stream directly using [`CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) (.NET 4 required):

```
using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    input.CopyTo(outputStream);
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch guys, am using outputStream.Write(newbuffer, 0, readCount);
it works fine but the code was suggested by another expert (DotNetuser) by stackoverflow,so i was trying to execute his code and it start throwing exception at ToArray,then i thought am missing something.That's why i asked here. Can you please take the "Minus" reputation whoever gave it to me.